# Embedding a PDF on a website with default zoom

Tags: html, pdf

I'm looking to embed a pdf file to a page, in a div about 700px wide. The pdf at 100% is wider than 700px so I want to zoom out enough to where you can see the entirety of each page without having to scroll.

I've tried several options without any luck, I had no idea this was going to be such an issue. The best solution so far has been using Google's Docs Viewer (https://docs.google.com/viewer) but I soon realized that there's a bandwidth limit and I'd exceeded it just from the few tests I ran. I also tried PDFObject but the zoom property didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.